# K-fold cross validation / partitioned models

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, cross-validation

I have a data set with 41 samples and 6 predictors. I used **treebagger** for classification trees in **Matlab**. Even though the oob error is high, the model predicted all the 41 labels accurately.

But then I tried to cross validate the model using k fold, the validation accuracy is only 41%. I am confused by this.

My other question is, how does the **k-fold algorithm** work when I try to cross-validate an already built ensemble model. Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you have 41 samples for both training and test? you train and test on the same 41 samples? please provide more details.

Comment: Yes, I have only 41 samples for both training and testing. I trained on the 41 samples using **treebagger** and then tested the same 41 samples and all were predicted accurately. However, the **k-fold** validation accuracy on the trained model is only 41%.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot train and test on the same data. The validation is meaningless.

K-fold cross-validation is to prevent that. You train on a subset and test on the remaining elements. Rinse and repeat with random subsets to improve the validation accuracy (not classification accuracy).

You cannot test with k-fold cross-validation a classifier that is already build. That just makes no sense.